# Java Page Rewriting

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing a java project.

I want to display an extention of any webpage as '.jsf' evenif it is 'jsp' or 'xhtml'.

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "display"? In the URL the browser sees? Why do you need to do this? What do you intend if you have two files aaa.xhtml and aaa.jsp, how would you manage such collisions? Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is done to hide actual file type from external visitor for page safety.

Comment: Adding the contents of your `web.xml` to the question would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just configure the `FacesServlet` accordingly?

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you *actually* meant "I want to block **direct** access to `*.jsp` and `*.xhtml` so that the visitor is forced to invoke them by `*.jsf`", then add a security constraint to `web.xml` on the desired `url-pattern`s and an empty `auth-constraint`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to JSP and XHTML files</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP and XHTML files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all request to to the servlet that needs to handle the jsf requests

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

STEPS (For new jsp project) :

1. In web.xml, change  to *.jsf
2. Change  to index.jsp
3. Create new welcome.jsp
4. In index.jsp page, include :

5. Run project and see extention in browser.

Comment: What is this? This doesn't look like an answer. If this is actually an update to your question, then you should have used the `edit` link.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for using JavaServer Faces, then the configuration of the JSF servlet enables the automatic mapping of .jsf to the underlying .xhtml or .jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it the wrong way round.

The user-agent will make requests to your servlet, with a given URI identifying the resource they wish to access.  **You decide** what the correct URI for a given resource is, and how to respond to this request.  So it's conceptually not a case of your webpage having an "address" that you want to display differently.  Rather, it's a case of what URIs you want to use to map to which resources.

If you don't want to expose the extension, then *you don't need URIs to have any extension at all*, they're just strings.  You will, however, need to think about how to resolve potential name clashes (as djna notes in the comment).  I believe that this is configured for you at the Faces level, and actually [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107942/java-page-rewriting/3109736#3109736) should have all the technical information necessary to do this.

I just wanted to point out the backwards nature of your thought processes, clearing this up will hopefully make it easier to grok the process in general.  It's better that you understand it, than simply paste something into your web.xml that makes the problem go away (for now).

Answer (score -1):

You should configure your server to process .jsf files as .jsp pages. How to actually do this depends on the server you are using - an information you haven't provided.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with either jsf or jsp, so I don't know what consequences this server modification will have on actual jsf pages.

Comment: This is not a server level configuration in servlet/jsp containers.